# Running jupyter ipynb with atom

Tags: jupyter-notebook, atom-editor

I installed `atom` and `jupyter package` for `atom` [from here](https://github.com/jupyter/atom-notebook). Now if I open old ipython notebooks from `atom` it does not display it as notebook. Here is what old piece of notebook looks like in `atom`,

```
{
 "cells": [
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": 2,
   "metadata": {
    "collapsed": false
   },
   "outputs": [],
   "source": [
    "#importing all the libraries\n",
    "import numpy as np\n",
    "import pandas as pd\n",
    "import sys \n",
    "sys.path.append(\"/Users/myname/Documents/things")\n",
    "import quadedge as qd\n",
    "sys.path.append(\"/Users/myname/Documents/otherthings\")\n",
    "import latdevcode as latdev\n",
    "import cendevcode as latgen\n",
    "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt"
   ]
  },
```

Am i missing something? How can I make the navigator directly open `jupyter notebook` in `atom` and properly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not even old notebooks.  I just installed python (3.6.3) and jupyter (4.3.0), created a couple notebooks via the Jupyter notebook CLI (nteract), but when I tried to open them in atom, I also got a JSON version.

After a fair bit of research, what I learned is that Hydrogen is simply *using* jupyter to enable inline code execution in plain text files (e.g. `.py` and `.R`), it *does not* actually support `.ipynb` files, more importantly ***the maintainers have no plans or desire to support `.ipynb`***.

references:
- https://github.com/nteract/hydrogen/issues/75
- https://github.com/nteract/hydrogen/issues/1154

Comment: Although that's a surprise (I'm googling around for a good Jupyter notebook in Atom), there is a niche for this sort of thing. If you want to use an interactive interface to develop production code, not expository notebooks, then you'd want this. I've been doing that in a hacked Emacs python-mode for about 15 years now, and it's a great way to work. Nevertheless, at the moment, I'm looking for something that does ipynb notebooks...